# creating biscuit-like material

Tags: materials

How can I render a biscuit-like material as shown in this picture?(I'm using blender cycles)

[image]

Comment: Please use the tools of this site to make the images part of the question and not an external link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: What part of the biscuit exactly? The yellow, crumbly texture or the pattern on top?

Comment: Yes i tried to achieve the same texture but i failed

Comment: I tried to add a texture of a cookie with a displacement map but i didn't turn out like what i excepted any help would be appreciated